# Fill a listview from a different class android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I want to fill and show a `listview` of the prime numbers.The `arraylist` of the PrimeNumbers class seems to be filled but when I want to assign it to the listview it won't work.

The problem is when the PrimeNumbersActivity is called from the handler the listview is not filled and nothing is showing in the new activity.
Would really appreciate some help.

> PrimeNumbers Class

```
public class PrimeNumbers {

public ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
public PrimeNumbers(ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers){
    this.primeNumbers = primeNumbers;
}

public PrimeNumbers() {

}
```

}

> Handler class

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Context context;

public MyHandler(ProgressDialog progressDialog, Context context) {
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    this.context = context;
}



@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    findPrimeNumber(Integer.parseInt(msg.obj.toString()));
}

public void findPrimeNumber(int number){

    ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean isPrimeNumber;
    PrimeNumbers primeNumbers1 = new PrimeNumbers(primeNumbers);




    for(int i = 2; i <= number; i++){
        isPrimeNumber = true;
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            try {
                sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(j != 1 && j != i){
                if(i%j == 0){
                    isPrimeNumber = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isPrimeNumber){
            primeNumbers.add(i);
        }
        progressDialog.setProgress(i*100/number);
        if(progressDialog.getProgress() == progressDialog.getMax()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),PrimeNumbersActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    for (int i :
            primeNumbers1.primeNumbers) {
        Log.d(TAG, i + "");
    }
}
```

}

> PrimeNumbersActivity class

```
public class PrimeNumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private PrimeNumbers primeNumbers = new PrimeNumbers();
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prime_numbers);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, primeNumbers.primeNumbers);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

}

Comment: I think you are making it too complicated. `new PrimeNumbers()` --> creates new object and `primeNumbers.primeNumbers` is not assigned. If you create object by `new PrimeNumbers(list)`  then `primeNumbers.primeNumbers` will have that list

Comment: You can directly find primenumbers in this activity and assign it to the adapter

Comment: @JyotiJK thank you for the answer. I have really tried to make an empty constructor but it didn't work as well. Do you have any sample code that could help?

Comment: You can try my answer or make your PrimeNumbers class as singleton. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try anyone,

1.use **`putExtra()`**,

```
intent.putExtra("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable) primeNumbers);
```

In your activity, change this line

```
ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, (ArrayList<Integer>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ARRAYLIST"));
```

2.Use **`singleton class`**

```
public class PrimeNumbers {
private static PrimeNumbers primenumbersOBJ=new PrimeNumbers();
public ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbersArray = new ArrayList<>();
public static PrimeNumbers getInstance(){
    return primenumbersOBJ;
}

private PrimeNumbers() {

}
```

In Handler class, before starting intent

```
PrimeNumbers.getInstance().primeNumbersArray=resultarray;
```

In your activity, use

```
PrimeNumbers.getInstance().primeNumbersArray
```

Comment: thank you. But the app crashed and it gave me this error when I used the 1st method "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.mohammed.tdservicesex1, PID: 28795
                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView"

Comment: @MohamedNajb please use         `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` since `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` is a linearlayout consists of 2 textviews.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.mohammed.tdservicesex1, PID: 28795 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView"

Comment: thank you so much now when I changed it to android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 it worked with the 1st method. I really appreciate the help